# модальное окно с периодичностью вывода

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Подскажите, как модифицировать скрипт, чтобы он выводил попап окно с периодичностью в сутки (независимо от посещаемых страниц, только один раз в день одному человеку при посещении любой страницы сайта)
Буду чрезмерно благодарен.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    if($(window).width() > 992) {


      var show_after = parseInt('50', 20);
      var autoclose_after = parseInt('', 20);
      setTimeout(function () {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
          items: {
            src: '#popup-11',
            type: 'inline'
          },
          tLoading: '',
          mainClass: 'popup-module mfp-with-zoom popup-type-1',
          removalDelay: 200,
        });

        if (autoclose_after > 0) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            $.magnificPopup.close();
          }, autoclose_after);
        }
      }, show_after);



    }

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

как-то так.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($(window).width() > 992) {
        let date = localStorage.getItem('popup-last-date');
        if(date!==null) {
            let NOW = new Date();
            let DATE = new Date(date);
            if(Math.round((NOW - DATE) / 1000 / 60 / 60/ 24) >= 1) {
                ShowPopUp();
            }
        } else {
            ShowPopUp();
        }
    }
    function ShowPopUp() {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '#popup-11',
                type: 'inline'
            },
            tLoading: '',
            mainClass: 'popup-module mfp-with-zoom popup-type-1',
            removalDelay: 200,
        });
        let NOW = new Date();
        localStorage.setItem('popup-last-date', NOW.getFullYear()+'-'+(NOW.getMonth()+1)+'-'+NOW.getDate())
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо,  но не работает((( Все равно окно появляется при последующих обновлениях..(

Comment: @ogd обновил. протестил - работает.

Comment: В сафари, в приватном режиме работать не будет. Потому что там в приватном режиме отключен `localStorage`.

Comment: как раз в сафари у меня работает, а вот в хроме нет... уже и куки почистил на всякий, а не работает...

Comment: @ogd какая версия?

Comment: 60.0.3112.113 хром, 10.1.2 сафари

Comment: @ogd посмотри консоль. может ошибка.

Comment: ошибок в консоле по скрипту нет..

Comment: @ogd попробуйте кеш почистить